How to achieve that Firefox web notifications onclick open a link in a new tab?
I allowed a Firefox web notifications to a few websites. The notifications work, but when I click on the notification box, only the notification box disappears, but I'd like it go to the particular webpage (at least to the root URL, better would be to the particular post or comment it notified me about).
I played with the settings in Firefox, for example
web.notifications.requireinteraction.enabled to True, but this didn't help, only the notification will stay longer. Is there a settings for what I need to achieve?

I think it has to do with poorly written notifications, not with a setting in firefox.
